# Max. number of rotations while inserting a new element into n-element red black tree

Tags: red-black-tree, tree-rotation

What is the maximum number of rotations while inserting a new element into `n`-element Red Black Tree?

If I'm correct, insertion that does not violate rules of RBT requries maximum of `2` rotations (2 cases). Assuming that's it, is `O(1)` also a correct answer?

If that's right, **confirm it** and please tell me, what requires maximum of 3 rotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maximum of 3 operations(or 2 rotations) are needed when implementing a Red-Black Tree correctly. For example the central BST shown in this image will need 3 operations to make it confirm to the Red Black BST's rules.

[image: Image to show a case when 3 operations are needed]

<sub>Image taken from Robert Sedgewick's slides from [this](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) MOOC.</sub>.